# python - cut a x-bit binary number to a byte (8bit)

Tags: python, binary, truncate

I am using python 2.7. I need to truncate a binary number from a x-bits to 8 bits (byte)
i will write an example of what i would like to do to make it clear and also because stackexchange doesn't leave me write my question for some reason, example:

```
0b1010101010100101 -> 0b10100101
```

i tried this workaround: converting it to string and then cutting it as a sub-string, but i didn't manage to make it working

```
str_cs = str(bin(cs))
str_cs = str_cs[to_cut:]
```

but i am facing many problem to convert it back to a binary number...
how would you truncate it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use a [bitwise `&`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) with a byte of all `1`s:

```
cs = cs & 0b11111111
# or, if you're feeling daring:
cs &= 0b11111111
```

Comment: The simplest solution as always... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solution of Phydeaux much better but I was doing :

```
>>> cs=0b1010101010100101
>>> cs=int(bin(cs)[-8:], 2)
>>> bin(cs)
'0b10100101'
```

Based on what you were trying with `str`

Comment: I tried it only now, i didn t know the possibility to choose the base with int(), thanks again